# Eclipse PDT weird folder order

Tags: eclipse, project, directory

I have a project with a weird folder order. It is not alphabetical, in fact I can't figure out what order it is actually in.

Please see screenshot on http://www.automatem.co.nz/Screenshot.png

Anyone have any ideas what setting would cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a normal order, since 1st 3 dirs are script dirs. If you want all dirs to be a-z, you have 2 options:

1. Remove 1st 3 dirs from script state. To remove them, right click on folder, then "exclude".
2. Make other dirs script dirs. To make them, right click on folder, then "use as source".

Answer (score 3):

It's alphabetical but with the folders that contain code on top. These folders have that little parcel icon.

Comment: ahm thanks. do you have any link to what the "parcel icon" means? All folders contain "code", however you may mean something different than me?