# Eclipse PDT with symfony project : how can I configure folder order?

Tags: symfony, eclipse-pdt

I use Eclipse PDT with Symfony projects (and the Eclipse plugin).
I currently have 2 symfony projects I'm working on, and I have trouble with the folder order : [image: http://i.imgur.com/oLMMp8K.png]

I found some elements here : [Eclipse PDT weird folder order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116721/eclipse-pdt-weird-folder-order) but it wasn't enough.

As you may have noticed, my 3 source folders "app" "web" and "src" are not display in the same order for both projects.
For first project it goes app-web-src, and for the second it goes app-src-web.
If I go in project properties->php->include path, there's nothing here. In build path I can't configure order.

What am I missing ? **How can we configure folder order in this view** ?
I'm not sure if this a problem or something I missed, or if the problem/feature is from eclipse or the symfony plugin ("symfony feature" says my installation details).
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in current PDT snapshot. Will be released with Eclipse Neon.0 (PDT 4.0). See also bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356629

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem many times... the only solution that worked for me was removing and adding the project again to Eclipse.
When the first one fails, the second one is ok.